# How to replace only certain spaces in a string?

Tags: vba

I created an import function for Data.

Sometimes the import string comes like this:

> 47588328 2020.06.25 11:42:13 buy 0.11 eurusd 1.12240 1.11902 0.00000
> 2020.06.25 14:05:04 1.11902 0.00 0.00 0.00 -35.35

and sometimes like this

```
45881875
2020.05.25 19:53:14
buy
0.10
eurusd
1.08975
1.08999
1.09503
2020.05.26 10:49:17
1.09503
0.00
0.00
-0.48
51.14
```

I split the values into an array. If the string is separated by line breaks there is no problem.

If the string comes separated with space I cant process it. I tried to replace the spaces with line breaks.
This would work but there are Date & Time parts. They have to stay together, and they do not when I replace spaces with line breaks.

I have this:

```
TextboxText = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
TextboxText = Replace(TextboxText, " ", vbLf)
```

One of my ideas was to build a loop which goes trough all the spaces, then just except the space number 2 and 10. For example with pseudo code:

```
> For Each Space in TextboxText     
>     If Not space nr = 2 or space nr = 10 Then
>         replace space
>     End if 
> Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say split it into an array as you have been doing (presumably using `split(strText)` then run back through the array to rejoin the date with the time. Something like the below

```
For x = LBound(myArray) to Ubound(myArray)
    'If IsDate(myArray(x)) Then - This didn't work as would erroneously return TRUE for decimals
    If Format(Cdate(myArray(x)), "yyyy") <> "1899" Then
        MyArray(x) = MyArray(x) & " " & MyArray(x+1) 'Join it to the value after
        MyArray(x+1) = "" 'Delete the value after (time value)
    End If
Next
```

Then anything you do thereafter with the array would just need to include e.g. `If MyArray(x) <> ""` to miss out those empty values.

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to be return true for IsDate even on strings like "0.11" - very weird

Comment: Hello Spencer Barnes

I really like your solution! quite sexy :) thanks so much for coming up with this. i like it because the dates can be anywhere in the string.. but as jamheadart says, the only problem is that it return true for IsDate not only with dates.. do you have an idea how to fix this? The Problem are values like "0.11", they are interpreted as a date, can we somehow exclude this? maybe with regex, but i dont know exactly how to work with them...

Comment: hmm ... have to say I didn't really test this exhaustively, just it was the first solution I thought of. Forgot that it would interpret decimals (0.11) as times (in this case 00:11:00) So, next fix; use `Cdate` instead of `IsDate` to check that it's actually a date not a time. Just editing it into the answer now...

Comment: @LucaS if it's any comfort I've never even heard of Regex. I've also just thought of a possibly more foolproof method; `If IsDate(myArray(x) & " " & myArray(x+1))` - that could be used instead, I think. Pick your favourite.

Comment: You are gorgeous :) i also found a solution, its possible to make an aditional check for the "?.??" pattern like this <TestCheck = myarray(X) Like "?.??"> and then just test with an if TestCheck = False statement.. But i guess your solution is better.. Thanks so much for your help... do you think its possible to delete this 2 empty values from the array? but only this 2 values, because its possible that there are other emtpy values... so the array would be exactly the same, otherwise it will be a little difficult with the further processing..

Comment: i found a way to delete the emtpy values and return a new array. it works like this        `ReDim NewArr(LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray))
        
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
 If myArray(i) <> "" Then
                
NewArr(j) = myArray(i)
j = j + 1
End If
Next i
        
ReDim Preserve NewArr(LBound(myArray) To j) `

Comment: That's great - glad it works for you! Good idea on creating a new array not containing the empty values.

Comment: I found an other isssue.. Also if use `If IsDate(myArray(x) & " " & myArray(x+1))` some numbers are interpreted as dates, which they are not.. I added one more check like this:              `like1 = MyArray(X) Like "#.##"`
                    `like2 = MyArray(X + 1) Like "#.#####"`
And then I test with an if statement if they are not true `If Not like1 = True And Not like2 = True Then Debug.Print "blabla" End If`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as clean as I'd originally hoped, I think there's probably a better way to do it but it does work:

```
Function GetSplit(s As String) 
Dim x As Variant: x = Split(s, " ")
Dim r(13) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
For i = 0 To 15
    If i = 1 Or i = 9 Then
        r(j) = x(i) & " " & x(i + 1)
        i = i + 1
    Else
        r(j) = x(i)
    End If
    j = j + 1
Next i
GetSplit = r
End Function
```

It just cycles through an array split by " " and moves across values in the same position unless they were in position 1 or 9 (space 2 or 10) in which case it concats and increases the 1st array counter by 1, used like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String: s = "47588328 2020.06.25 11:42:13 buy 0.11 eurusd 1.12240 1.11902 0.00000 2020.06.25 14:05:04 1.11902 0.00 0.00 0.00 -35.35"
Dim resultArray As Variant
    resultArray = GetSplit(s)
End Sub
```

Of course this all only works if those strings you get come in exactly the same format each time, I hope those dates don't move about!

**Edit**

I tried editing this one to utilise `IsDate` to make it more dynamic but `IsDate` is returning true for lots of the strings in there, e.g. "0.11" is a date, and it even returned false for an actual date (probably due to regional settings)

Answer (score 0):

This one returns a string directly without looping but it also relies on the premise that your date position will never change and a magic "`<dt>`" placeholder string!

```
Function GetSplit2(s As String) As String
Dim x As Variant: x = Split(s, " ")
    s = Replace(s, x(1) & " " & x(2), x(1) & "<dt>" & x(2))
    s = Replace(s, x(9) & " " & x(10), x(9) & "<dt>" & x(10))
    s = Replace(s, " ", vbCrLf)
    GetSplit2 = Replace(s, "<dt>", " ")
End Function
```

Use like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String: s = "47588328 2020.06.25 11:42:13 buy 0.11 eurusd 1.12240 1.11902 0.00000 2020.06.25 14:05:04 1.11902 0.00 0.00 0.00 -35.35"
MsgBox GetSplit2(s)
End Sub
```